# vscode tasks: specifying .cpp files recursively

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I cannot find a way to tell my tasks.json file to do what I want:
for now, to build my project I use this:

```
"args": [
            "/DEBUG",
            "/Zi",
            "/EHsc",
            "/std:c++latest",
            "/MDd",
            "/MP",

            "/Fe:", "${workspaceFolder}/client/build/x64_Debug/client.exe",

            "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/*.cpp",
            "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/imgui/*.cpp",
            "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/game/*.cpp",
            "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/entity/*.cpp",
            "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/ammunition/*.cpp",
            "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/enemy/*.cpp",
            "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/particules/*.cpp",
            "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/client/*.cpp",

            "/I", "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/include/",
            "/I", "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/include/imgui/",
            "/I", "${workspaceFolder}/vendor/SFML_x64/SFML-2.5.1/include",
              
            ....
```

It works just fine, however, I'd like to get rid of the fact that I need to `"${workspaceFolder}/client/src/every/single/subfolder/*.cpp"`

I know I can do something like this "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/**"
Which would put every single file, given there's only .cpp files, but I'd like to put my header files next to their source file.

So is there a way to tell `"select every .cpp files under /src/subfolders"` & `"select every .h files under /src/subfolders"` ?

Be it a good practice or not.

Comment: Take a look at CMake.

Comment: I'd like to stick with tasks :|

Comment: use CMake as task, looks like you have more than 2-3 files. And your command line has limited length

Comment: CMake as task & limited cmd length. Interesting, I'll look into it, thanks.